# Proof of small-o statement

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics

Definition: given a sequence $a_n = o(b_n)$ if $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \to 0$

Given that $a_n$, $b_n$, $c_n$, $d_n$ >0,

If $a_n = o(c_n)$, $b_n = o(d_n)$, Show that $a_n + b_n = o (c_n+ d_n)$

My thought:
Given that $\frac{a_n}{c_n} \to 0$ and $\frac{b_n}{d_n} \to 0 $

To show $a_n + b_n = o (c_n+ d_n)$ , I have to show $\frac{a_n + b_n}{c_n+d_n} \to 0$, which means I have to show $\frac{a_n}{c_n+d_n} \to 0$ and $\frac{b_n}{c_n+d_n} \to 0 $. I'm just stuck on getting those two fraction to converge to 0.

Comment: Since $a_n, c_n, d_n > 0$, we have $0 < \frac{a_n}{c_n + d_n} < \frac{a_n}{c_n}$, so...

Comment: @TheoBendit sorry I still don't see how $\frac{a_n}{c_n}$ > $\frac{a_n}{c_n+d_n}$ > 0 implies $\frac{a_n}{c_n+d_n} \to 0$, could you explain this part?

Comment: @DataBall an application of the squeeze theorem will show that $\frac{a_n}{c_n+d_n}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, which is part of what you wanted to show.

Comment: @AlannRosas I see it now, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

If $c_n\ge 0$ and $d_n\ge 0$ for all but finitely many $n,$ then for any $\delta >0,$ take $n_1,n_2$ such that

$n>n_1\implies (c_n\ge 0 \land |a_n|\le c_n\delta)$

and $n>n_2\implies (d_n\ge 0 \land |b_n|\le d_n\delta).$

Let $n_3=\max (n_1,n_2).$ Then $$n>n_3\implies |a_n+b_n|\le |a_n|+|b_n|\le $$ $$\le (c_n+d_n)\delta=$$ $$=|c_n+d_n|\cdot \delta.$$

This is not valid if $c_n$ or $d_n$ have different non-$0$ signs for infinitely many $n$. For example if  for all $n$ we had $a_n=b_n=1$ and $c_n=n$ and $d_n=-n.$